# How should I get time in minutes in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am storing large amount of data in VBA and later on exporting that file in excel.
I am able to collect the time if it is greater than an hour, but if it is less than 59 minutes I am not able to collect it.
I am using similar function for calculating time difference

1. // get the time diff 00:00
2. var time = TIMEDIFF('00:00', $inspection_time);
3. // for example, the inspection time is 12:00pm, the result should be 0.5
4. var rate = time/24;
5. SETRESULT(rate);

Answer (score 0):

First off, `TIMEDIFF` is a function I did not immediately find documentation for.

Also, time/dates are usually represented in terms of days.

To get hours from that you would **multiply** by 24 to get hours (then 60 for minutes, etc., etc.), not divide.

#### Using an Existing Function

A simple way to calculate time differences using a built in function is with `DateDiff`which has a signature of:

```
DateDiff( interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear] )
```

There are plenty of intervals for you to choose from, ranging from year to second. Minutes is "n".

Ex:

```
DateDiff("n", "00:00", "12:00") '-> Result: 0.5
```

Documentation: [msdn.microsoft.com/.../datediff-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datediff-function)

#### Simple Math Version

Even simpler is to just subtract:

```
abs(time2 - time1)
```

Where the result will be in days.

**EDIT:**

I would encourage you to make sure your functions do exactly what you expect them to do and not just hack something together that works but upon further changes breaks. It's poor coding practice and you learn nothing from it.

However, in an effort to give a response, a simple roundabout way to get a minimum cutoff of one hour would be to simply take the smallest value you would like to have, compare it to your value and choose the larger of the two.

```
calculatedValue <- SomeNumber
cutoffValue <- 1/24
chosenValue <- MAX(calculatedValue, cutoffValue)
```

Comment: The var rate = time/24 is used for some other function.. And I can't change this logic because it is applied to a very large Program. Can we do something like if the time is between 1-59 min it displays/give us the output as 1 hour

Comment: Thank you @Randomness Slayer.  I haven't coded this, My company's coder has and I am just debugging the errors. :p. I"ll try and look into this logic, whether it will apply on the code or no. and thanks again